# Cant remove Javascript JsLint error in Aptana using inline code

Tags: javascript, jenkins, aptana, jslint, jshint

I have the following Lint errors with the following javascript function

```
getColor: function (color) {
    var result = "";
    switch (color) {
    case "RESET":
        result =  "\033[0m";
        break;
    case "BLACK":
        result =  "\033[30m";
        break;
    case "RED":
        result =  "\033[31m";
        break;
    case "GREEN":
        result =  "\033[32m";
        break;
    case "YELLOW":
        result =  "\033[33m";
        break;
    case "BLUE":
        result =  "\033[34m";
        break;
    case "MAGENTA":
        result =  "\033[35m";
        break;
    case "CYAN":
        result =  "\033[36m";
        break;
    case "WHITE":
        result =  "\033[37m";
        break;
    }
    return result;

},
```

I have tried wrapping it in

```
 /*ignore jslint start*/  /*ignore jslint end*/
```

but this doesn't work.

Ive looked at http://jslinterrors.com/octal-literals-are-not-allowed-in-strict-mode/

and it says to implement

```
/*jshint -W115 */
```

any ideas on how to do or the jslint equivalent inline as i need the code to pass a Jenkins build ?

Comment: I think [you're out of luck](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L933). JSLint isn't always particularly flexible. Though if you can edit the JSLint source your build is using, you can certainly change the octal hating limitation.

Comment: hmm yeah i think your right

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the octal escape sequences to hex or Unicode escape sequences?

For example, `"\x1B[0m"` and `"\u001B[0m"` are both the same *exact* string as `"\033[0m"`, but JSLint is happy with them.